# Export sharepoint group and users to cvs using powershell in a particular format

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I have been able to export Groups and users in this format

Groups    Users

GroupA    User A; User A1

GroupB    UserB; User B1

Using this code below

```
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
 
#Get All Groups from Site - Exclude system Groups
$Groups = Get-PnPGroup | Where-Object {$_.OwnerTitle -ne "System Account"}
$GroupData=@()
 
#Get Group Details
ForEach($Group in $Groups)
{
    #Get Group data
    $GroupData += New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
    "Group Name" = $Group.Title
    "Users" = $Group.Users.Title -join "; "
    })
}
$GroupData
 
#Export Users data to CSV file
$GroupData | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $CSVFile
```

But what i'm after is

Groups    Users

GroupA   User A

GroupA   User A1

GroupB    UserB

GroupB   User B1

Is this achievable and if yes  how can i do that in powershell?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change it to this:

```
ForEach($Group in $Groups)
{
    #Get Group data
    foreach($user in $Group.users){
    $GroupData += New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
    "Group Name" = $Group.Title
    "Users" = $user.Title
    })
 }
}
#Export Users data to CSV file
$GroupData | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $CSVFile
```